# Javascript isnt loaded from an external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I removed all my javascript and put it in an external link:

```
<script type="text/javascrpt" src="javascript/FooterJavascript.js"></script>
```

When I go to the website and click the link..all the javascript is there.

The file has got different functions and events..such as hover effects..it starts like this:

```
                                $(document).ready(function(){
```

Why the hover effects that is inside that file arent loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascrpt" src="javascript/FooterJavascript.js">
                    ^^^^^^^^
                  here is the error
```

must be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/FooterJavascript.js">
```

**edit:**

to see in neatbean

if wrong than there in different background color in the script body

[image]

now what happen when script tag is right ...ya, now the different background color indicate that everything is ok

[image]

Comment: Also, just a note that if you leave off the `type` attribute on a `script` tag it will default to `text/javascript`. This is a personal preference, however, and most code you'll see will include the `type` attribute.

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd no..buddy it have but you might be mistaken to recognize ill add in my answer